# better alternatives to sharp or gm for resizing images on aws lambda with node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, image-resizing

I have been trying to create a working image resizer in lambda and following various examples and code I see out there to do it in node.js

I tried gm with imagemagick tools but there seems to be a built-in buffer limit which causes it to fail in the lambda environment on large images.

I tried using sharp but it keeps running into errors looking for libvips and the documentation is a cluster@#$^ and I can't seem to find a succinct "do this to get it to work" instruction anywhere.

So I'm yet again looking for some kind of a tool that can be run in node.js in the lambda environment to resize an image from an s3 download stream and re-upload the end result back to another S3 bucket. I need to also be able to get the image pixel dimensions while resizing it.
It needs to be able to handle large images without puking and not require a doctorate in amazon linux to install on lambda. I've wasted too much time on this aspect of this project already.

Any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Alas with much banging of my face on the keyboard intermittently, I eventually found a magic combination of using the docker run 'npm install' syntax on the sharp installation page combined with setting that particular script up to node.js v10.x that got it working on my third attempt. (I have no idea what was different from the first attempts, but I'm still figuring out how serverless deploy works for combined functions as well - too much 'new stuff' all in one project *sigh*)

Comment: Hi could you please explain more in details how did you get it to work?

Comment: unfortunately, i can't really. for one that was a while ago. For another, as I stated, I'm not really sure what combination eventually worked.